# How to make modal have false value after being opened once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Whenever I load my component, I load a modal with instruction, I want it to happen only once. When user press f5 i don't want to show this modal anymore unless he triggers it with a button. How can I set this up, do I need a computed function with localStorage?

component
`InstModal(:toggleModal="instructionModal" @ok="instructionModal = false")`

setup

```js
const instructionModal = ref(false)
setTimeout(() => (instructionModal.value = true), 2000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need localStorage, so that you can persist this across different sessions. You don't need computed to acheive what you want, tho. Let's say you want to store it in localStorage with a key of `instructionModalOpened`:

```
const instructionModal = ref(+localStorage.getItem('instructionModalOpened') || false)
setTimeout(() => {
    instructionModal.value = true;
    localStorage.setItem('instructionModalOpened', '1') 
}, 2000);
```

However, if `instructionModal` can be mutated in other places of your code, you are better off watching it, i.e.:

```
const instructionModal = ref(+localStorage.getItem('instructionModalOpened') || false)
setTimeout(() => {
    instructionModal.value = true;
}, 2000);

watch(instructionModal, (val) => {
    if (!val) return;
    localStorage.setItem('instructionModalOpened', '1') 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, what does the ref(`+` mean?

Comment: For some reason it still keep loading every time I press f5

Comment: @Zeus It's an unary operator that converts the `'1'` string stored into a number

Comment: do I need to also do something with localStorage while closing the modal?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Because right now, when I close the modal, it opens again after a sec, also it keeps appearing on each refresh of the page.